# Java Verify xml digital signature using public key

Tags: java, digital-signature

I have a signed xml document which has been signed by private_key.pfx.

Now I have a public_key.cert file which start from :

```
====== BEGIN OF =======
jksbfjkbckcnJKNBCKSJJksncs==

====== END OF==========
```

Now, I want to verify signed xml document using my public_key.cer

How can I do this ?

Please Help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look for the `<Signature>` element in your signed document.  There are methods in the Java XML Digital Signature API you can use to verify the signature such as [`XMLSignature.validate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/crypto/dsig/XMLSignature.html).

If you check out this article: [Programming With the Java XML Digital Signature API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/dig-signature-api-140772.html).

> key steps in validating an XML signature.
>
> ```
> // Find Signature element.
> NodeList nl =
>     doc.getElementsByTagNameNS(XMLSignature.XMLNS, "Signature");
> if (nl.getLength() == 0) {
>     throw new Exception("Cannot find Signature element");
> }
>
> // Create a DOMValidateContext and specify a KeySelector
> // and document context.
> DOMValidateContext valContext = new DOMValidateContext
>     (new X509KeySelector(), nl.item(0));
>
> // Unmarshal the XMLSignature.
> XMLSignature signature = fac.unmarshalXMLSignature(valContext);
>
> // Validate the XMLSignature.
> boolean coreValidity = signature.validate(valContext);
> ```
>
> First, you must find the location of the Signature element that you
>   wish to validate. One way to do this is to use the DOM
>   getElementsByTagNameNS method as shown in Code Sample 5. The second
>   block of code creates a DOMValidateContext object containing a
>   KeySelector object and a reference to the Signature element. The
>   purpose of the KeySelector object is to obtain the public key using
>   the information in the KeyInfo element and hand it back to be used as
>   the validation key. The next section will discuss KeySelectors in more
>   detail. The last two lines of code unmarshal and validate the
>   signature. The validate method returns true if the signature is valid
>   and false if it is invalid.